Concatenating mathematical formula with dollar sign
With jQuery, I'm doing some math to calculate a price. The math works, but I want to put a dollar sign in front of it, and when I try adding "$" + into the code, the math stops working correctly. How can I get the value of #totalprice to include the dollar sign?
$('#totalprice').val("$" + $('#qty1').val() * $('#price1').val() + $('#qty2').val() * $('#price2').val());


Your brackets don't match.

I accidentally left it out when pasting my code here. That's not what the issue is. I was asking about how to get the dollar sign to appear without figuring into the equation.

Assuming in your example that .val() is returning a number, consider what JavaScript would do with that number when you do this:
"$" + $('#qty1').val()

The value "$" isn't a number.  (After all, what would $ + 5 equal?)  It's a string.  So JavaScript coerces the number value into a string and concatenates.
Basically the + operator means something different with strings than it does with numbers.
Perform your logic in two distinct steps.  First use the numbers to calculate a result, then concatenate that result into an output string.  You can do this on the same line of code by grouping your mathematical expression with parentheses.  For example:
"$" + ($('#qty1').val() * $('#price1').val() + $('#qty2').val() * $('#price2').val())


You are probably concatenating strings and not numbers because you start your argument with "$".
Put some parenthesis around your math calculations (after "$" +).
Also don't forget to parse all those *.val() calls if you need to.
And close your global .val() call; you forgot the last parenthesis.
